# Getting 'Access Denied' on multiple websites

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

As the title says, I am getting an 'Access Denied' message on multiple websites. The exact message is:

> Access Denied
>   You don't have permission to access "website name" on this server.

The sites that I have discovered so far are `homedepot.com`, `costco.com`, and `lowes.com`. I have been getting the same message on all of the websites, besides the reference codes, which I will list below:

```
www.costco.com:    Reference #18.15393717.1541289653.5c399d2  
www.lowes.com:     Reference #18.bf273017.1541289827.c064f1  
www.homedepot.com: Reference #18.84273017.1541289848.52e1d8
```

My home's router is a [Linksys EA9400 AC5000 Tri-Band MU-MIMO Wi-Fi Router](https://www.linksys.com/us/support-product?pid=01t34000003XEgrAAG), and my family and I have tried this on multiple devices, including a Windows PC, an iPhone, and an iPad, and I tried clearing my cookies on all of them, but it confirmed that it was a router problem, not a device problem.

What should I do to try and fix this problem?

Edit: Just rebooted the router, still not working. I'll upload screenshots as soon as I can.

Edit 2:

### DNS:

[image: DNS 1] [image: DNS 2]

### With WiFi:

[image: With Wifi]

### Without WiFi:

[image: Without Wifi]

### ipconfig /all

[image: ipconfig /all]

Edit 3: Added another picture to DNS Servers

Edit 4: Added ipconfig /all

Edit 5: `homedepot.com` works now, but the others still don’t

Edit 6: All of the sites work now, problem solved, I guess? Don't know why the websites were blocked though, that was kind of weird.

Comment: Please edit the question with this info : If you turn off wifi on the phone, and visit the same site, what do you see?  Can you take a screenshot of one of the Reference messages, whole browser window?  You may want to blur out userID in the screenshot, then upload to imgur.com or similar, then post the link in your question.  Last piece of data to find out : What DNS server(s) are you using when connected to this wifi router?

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue and/or aggressive ISP content filtering.  I would Reset the router to rule it out of the equation.

Comment: Try setting the IP settings to use a different DNS server than what DHCP may be assigning perhaps. Maybe `8.8.8.8` or `75.75.75.75` or `1.1.1.1`. What results do you get when set like that with one of those? If that solves the problem, then consider going into your router and changing the DNS address that is tells DHCP to give to client machines that request an IP from it.

Comment: Those DNS servers are really sketchy. The fec0 IPv6 prefix is reserved and has been deprecated since 2004. That IPv4 address looks sketchy too, unless that’s the NAT private subnet for your LAN for some reason (is it?). You need to find out for sure where those addresses are coming from. It could be some kind of adware/malware that’s acting as a fake DHCP server and DNS server on your local network in order to keep your systems compromised or serve ads.

Comment: @Spiff The IPv4 address is my router's IP address, I'll try to figure out what's going on with my IPv6 addresses

Comment: It's not uncommon to have cross-domain POST attack change settings in your router if you leave it with the manufacturer password. You probably got your router's DNS settings poisoned with a malicious server that will attempt to prevent you from reaching some websites, that usually include websites where you try to find help for your problem. I advise you to reset the router settings to factory defaults and set it up anew, and for your own sake use a password that doesn't suck.

Comment: Did you configure that IPv4 address yourself?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch No, not that I know of, someone else in my family might've though

Comment: @Havenard We've had our password different from the default as soon as we set it up

Comment: Take a picture of ipconfig /all

Comment: @Coloradohusky I didn't mean the Wi-Fi password, it's the router admin password.

Comment: @Havenard Sorry, I wasn't very clear, that's what I meant

Comment: @HazardousGlitch Added link in post

Comment: Try : (1) Another browser, (2) Clear browser cache and reset its settings, (3) Try some VPN and if this works then it's your ISP, (4) In Internet Options select Delete and clear everything.

Comment: The IP setup is really weird, even for a custom configuration. I'd reset the router to factory defaults and see if it works like Ramhound suggested.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch Ok, I'll try that later tonight, once everyone's off the Wi-Fi and I get my dad's permission

Comment: How did you make out?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch It solved itself about three days ago, all websites work now! Kind of weird why it did that though, I wish I knew why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved itself on November 6th, don't know what happened here but all's well now!

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool to check if your IP has been blacklisted and why. Then you may request an investigation.

I have requested an investigation from the Akamai team and voila! Problem solved :) The websites have been unblocked for me. I just wonder if it was Akamai or the UPC somehow?
For all who encounter a similar problem, use this tool:
https://www.akamai.com/us/en/clientrep-lookup/